# angular dart js interop with async / promise awaited in client

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-js-interop

clientside.js

```
async function callClientAsyncFuncWithResult () {

    let result = await someService.request();
    return result;
}
```

page.dart

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

var result = js.context.callMethod('callClientAsyncFuncWithResult'); 

//I want to do something like var result = await js.context.callMethod('callClientAsyncFuncWithResult');
```

How in AngularDart do you wait for a client side javascript Promise to return with result before continuing execution in dart? Right now it just flows over the call and I've tried setting the result of callMethod to Future or Promise and it never waits.

I don't think my implementation is correct. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily convert a Javascript Promise to a Dart Future, by using the `convertNativePromiseToDartFuture` API, which is available in `dart:html_common`.

A simple implementation might look like :

Javascript :

```
function myCoolFunc () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(myLongAwaitedData);
  });
}
```

Dart Interop file :

```
@JS()
library coolLib;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'dart:async';

@JS()
external Future<T> myCoolFunc ();
```

Dart file :

```
import 'dart:html_common';
import 'cool_lib.dart';

main() async {
  var myVar = await convertNativePromiseToDartFuture(myCoolFunc());
  print(myVar);
}
```

I found this deeply buried in the Gitter of the Dart Sdk. I hope it can help future Angular Dart users.

Update : [This API has changed in Dart 2.6](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-html/promiseToFuture.html) `convertNativePromiseToDartFuture` has been replaced with `promiseToFuture`

Comment: @SlimShady Updated answer to reflect new API